# Describe the differential of $d\phi : \mathbb{T}_{t, \mathbb{A^1}} \rightarrow \mathbb{T}_{t^3, t^4, t^5, W}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $V = \mathbb{A^1}$ and $W = Z(xz - y^2, yz, x^3, z^2 - x^2y) \subset \mathbb{A^3}$ and let $\phi: V \rightarrow W$ be a surjective morphism, describe the differential.

Currently in a course in Commutative Algebra and I've never taken a course in geometry. When I see the word differential, I think of derivatives. But I'm unsure how to exactly approach this in the sense of derivatives. Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: There is a purely algebraic definition of derivatives. I suggest you read about differentials in an algebraic geometry or commutative algebra book, then try and solve the problem.

Comment: @Manos Any books on algebraic geometry/commutative algebra that you could recommend that would have an explanation?

Comment: @George Try Shafarevich.'

Comment: @George: Eisenbud too.